# Add new column in SQL and the string is from existing column

Tags: sql, alter-table

I have this column in my database which is called `test_type`. The column is filled with string similar to:

```
TP-ABC01-01-2700-W-003
```

I want to create a new column called `test_type_no` and fills the new column by extracting some strings from `test_type` column. The expected string is:

```
ABC01-01
```

So far, I have tried:

```
alter table project_list 
    add column test_type_no varchar(255) 
         as (substring_index(substring_index(test_type, '-', 3), '-', -2))
```

But the query results error which said `syntax error at or near "as"`

How do I supposed to write my query in order to create new column with the expected string?

Comment: which dbms r you using?

Comment: Are you wanting to add a Non-persisted Computed Column, Persisted Computed Column, or a new normal column that's prepopulated with a computed value?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Indeed. Comment deleted :)

Answer (score 0):

If your version of MySQL database does *not* support computed columns (which appears to be the case), then just define the column and then do an update across the entire table:

```sql
ALTER TABLE project_list ADD COLUMN test_type_no VARCHAR(255);
UPDATE project_list
SET test_type_no = SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(test_type, '-', 3), '-', -2);
```

That being said, given that you want a virtual column, and that the `test_type_no` is really derived, you might just want to select it out when you query, or maybe create a view, instead of the above approach.